# IndexedDB for JavaFX Webview with no WebSQL support

Tags: java, javafx, indexeddb

I am attempting to load a webapp that requires IndexedDB in my JavaFX webview application. JavaFX does not support IndexedDB, so I am trying to shim in support for that using Javascript.

I am executing the shim here: https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim using the WebEngine class in JavaFX. I see that window.shimIndexedDB is an object, however, when I call window.shimIndexedDB.__useShim() I get the following:

```
This browser does not have WebSQL to shim.
```

I did some googling but I didn't find a similar shim solution to make WebSQL available for this IndexedDB shim. Nor did I find any IndexedDB shim that doesn't require WebSQL.

I'm wondering if no WebSQL support means I am screwed here? Or is there some other work around?

Comment: Does JavaFX just let you use browser globals, e.g., `window.indexedDB`? I presume the environment it works with is a modern one, in which case `indexedDB` should be supported.

Comment: `window.shimIndexedDB` is set by the shim, so it does support browser globals. However, WebSQL is not supported, which is the error message I get when I try to force the shim to provide `window.indexedDB`

Comment: I mean, if you don't use the shim, there is no way to access the `window.indexedDB` global?

Comment: No, thats the problem, window.indexedDB is not defined, because JavaFX webview does not support it. Hence the need for the shim, but it looks like JavaFX also doesn't support the dependency of the shim...

Comment: If you can't find an IndexedDB shim for Java, yes, IndexedDBShim assumes WebSQL support, and the Node implementation of IndexedDBShim does this using node-websql which converts the commands for an underlying SQLite database. Sorry, I can't be of further help, as don't really know anything about JavaFX.